# Code to Insert multiple photos from google drive to inside cells in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

I was able to find some code and tweak it to upload multiple imags to drive ( thanks to tanaikech ) 
but I failed to create URL of the shared photos and paste them in google spread sheet 
below is my sample code.gs

```
    function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function saveFile(obj) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
 var file=DriveApp.createFile(blob);
 var fileId= file.getId()
  return fileId



  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);


        var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+fileId;
  Logger.log(fileUrl);

 var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12bhRyuHXzcMP7AS8cHhtkp2Sa6kDObZYRT1FY13appU/edit#gid=0";
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
 var ws= ss.getSheetByName("DB");


     ws.appendRow([fileUrl]);

     return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);  

}
```

And my Index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
<input type='button' value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()'>

   
<script>
function getFiles() {
  const f = document.getElementById('files');
  [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
        console.log(id);
      }).saveFile(obj);
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is a link of my google sheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12bhRyuHXzcMP7AS8cHhtkp2Sa6kDObZYRT1FY13appU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks,

Comment: In your script, in the function of `saveFile`, the script is finished by `return fileId`. By this, the script for putting the URL is not run. So please remove `return fileId`. By the way, in this Javascript, the file is uploaded with the asynchronous process. By this, the URL is appended row by row. How about this?

Comment: It Worked !!! , how to put links of multiple files to be on the same rows instead of row by row. Thank you Tanaike you have a wonderful library

Comment: Thank you for your quick replying. About `how to put links of multiple files to be on the same rows instead of row by row.`, I cannot understand. You want to put the URLs to one row every upload. And your issue is still not resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Each upload paste the links in one row this solved ,If I uploaded 2 files at the same time it takes 2 rows so the links to go in one row

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot still understand about your current issue. When 2 files are uploaded by one uploading, you want to put 2 URLs to one row. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes exactly that what I want " put 2 URLs in one Row " , thanks for taking time to asnwer me Tanaike.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your current issue. So I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For examplw, when 2 files are uploaded by one uploading, you want to put 2 URLs to one row.

I could understand like above. And I could confirm that above understanding is correct from [your replying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066104/code-to-insert-multiple-photos-from-google-drive-to-inside-cells-in-google-sheet?noredirect=1#comment106233716_60066104). In this case, how about the following modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- In your script, the file is uploaded with the asynchronous process. By this, the URLs are put row by row. In order to put the URLs to one row every upload process, at first, the URL is required to be retrieved. And then, the URLs are put to one row.

When this is reflected to your script, please modify as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side: Code.gs

Please modify the function of `saveFile` and add new function of `putUrls` as follows. Please set the Spreadsheet URL.

```
function saveFile(obj) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  var file=DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  var fileId= file.getId()
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK,DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  var fileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+fileId;
  return fileUrl;
}

function putUrls(urls) {
  Logger.log(urls)
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###/edit#gid=0";  // <--- Please set this.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("DB");
  ws.appendRow(urls);
}
```

#### HTML and Javascript side: index.html

Please modify the Javascript as follows.

```
<script>
function saveFile(f, file, i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((url) => resolve(url)).withFailureHandler(e => reject(e)).saveFile(obj);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}

async function getFiles() {
  let urls = [];
  const f = document.getElementById('files');
  for (var i = 0; i < f.files.length; i++) {
    const url = await saveFile(f, f.files[i], i).catch(e => console.log(e));
    urls.push(url);
  }
  google.script.run.putUrls(urls);
}
</script>
```

- In this modification, the files are uploaded with the synchronous process and the URLs are put to an array. Then, the array is processed at `putUrls`.

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

Comment: Its worked perfect , thanks for the suggested modifications .

Comment: @Aboude zoua Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.